# Isn't notifyDataSetChanged enough to force an adapter to redisplay the items it holds?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

In a direct subclass of `PagerAdapter` in construction I pass in an empty `List<String>` that is the list to use for its functionality.
Then in another background task I fetch/create the strings that should be passed to the derived adapter and from my fragment I do: `derivedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.
Inside my `derivedAdapter` I have overriden this method as follows:

```
@Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(getCurrentCreatedList());
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But the view pager, which I have set this adapter does not display anything. Am I misunderstanding something about the adapters and notifyDataSetChanged()?

Note: If I start the adapter with a full list, everything works perfectly

**Update:**
If I also recreate the adaptor at that point and reset it it also works fine. Only updating via notifyDataSetChanged does not seem to work.
Perhaps I am misunderstanding what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Are you sure here `getCurrentCreatedList()` return some items not empty list?

Comment: @user370305:Yes I am sure. I went through a debugger and the list is ok.

Comment: Are you calling it in the UI thread? If called on the background thread it shouldn't refresh the view

Comment: @jlhonora:Aha! I am calling it when I receive an event from a BroadcastReceiver. That is not UI thread right? What is the best way to run it in the UI thread then?

Comment: onReceive does run on the UI thread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent) (main thread == UI thread). Just to be sure you could try running it in the UI thread with the runOnUiThread method

Comment: @jlhonora:This: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });` did not work

Comment: I have used almost the same setup as you do (Background task, BroadcastReceiver, notifyDataSetChanged), but subclassing ArrayAdapter<T>. The other difference is that I don't override notifyDatasetChanged, I clear, addAll and notify directly in the BR's callback